# How can the order of fields be preserved while saving a document in MongoDB with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

We are trying to save location logs in a collection. The mongoose schema is defined as below -

`{ user: { type: String, required: true }, location: { longitude: {type: Number}, latitude: type: { type: Number}}`

We save a location log through our code (usage is as below) -

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({user: 1},
  {location:{longitude: 9.0, latitude: 10.0}},
  function(err) {...});
```

On querying the database through 3T MongoChef, we observe that the order in which the location object is saved is not consistent, which results in wrong indexing of geo-locations. Even if two users have the same location, we only get the result in which the ordering of the keys is in the format `(latitude, longitude)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's not a bug. But you can reassemble location in `presave` hook:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.location = {
    latitude: this.location.latitude,
    longitude: this.location.longitude,
  };

  next();
});
```

Hope this helps.